# Blocking stdin while sleep

Tags: c, multithreading, io, stdin

I'm making copy of console snake game and have problem with blocking input.

I made the `agetch ()` function that processes user input in a separate thread, blocks input when the program is sleeping, and returns the character code. I tried this with `select ()` in Linux, instead of threads, but I ran into the same problem. I think the function is terrible and I hope you will help me fix it:

```c
#define nullptr ((void *) 0)

void* _agetch(void* arg)
{
    *(int32_t *) arg = getch();

    return nullptr;
}

int32_t agetch(uint32_t interval)
{
    int32_t status, status_addr;
    int32_t res = 0;

    pthread_t gp;
    status = pthread_create(&gp, nullptr, _agetch, &res);
    sleep(interval);

    if (res == 0)
        pthread_cancel(gp);
    else
        pthread_join(gp, (void**) &status_addr);

    return res;
}

int main()
{
    int32_t c;
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        c = agetch(3);
        if (c == 0) printf("Oops, timeout\n");
        else        printf("The char is %c\n" c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In first 3 seconds I pressed on the keyboard 4 times (e.g. "42ne") and I expect:

```
The char is 4
Oops, timeout
Oops, timeout
```

But I've got:

```
The char is 4
The char is 2
The char is n
```

Comment: Try putting `sleep(4)` in `_agetch()` just before setting `arg`. It will definitely give the output you desire! If it does, do think about what actually happened when you put `sleep()`.